# Pygame mixer in loop

Tags: python, pygame

I am designing a game on pygame and voice recognition where different images will be displayed, and the user has to say the name of the object they are seeing. If they give the right answer, the program will play an audio file "good job" and move to the next pic. Otherwise, it will play "wrong answer try again" and promote the user for a second chance to answer the same question; it will happen three times. My problem is that after the last chance, the audio file "wrong answer try again" will be played and move to the next question instead of loping again. How can I skip playing the "wrong answer try again'" for the last time I loop?

Thanks.

```
for i in range(1,11):
       
       
       if i== 1:

            carImg = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path,'tiger.jpg'))
            gameDisplay.blit(carImg,(130,0))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.mixer.Sound.play(Tiger)
            pygame.mixer.music.stop()
            time.sleep(7)
            for j in range(1,4):
                    r = sr.Recognizer()
                    with sr.Microphone() as source:
            
                     print ('Say Something!')
                     audio = r.listen(source)
                    try:
                        text = r.recognize_google(audio)
                        print(text)
                    except:
                        print('Did not get that try Again')
                        text=''
            
                    if text == 'tiger':
                        print('good job') 
                        pygame.mixer.Sound.play(right)
                        pygame.mixer.music.stop()
                        break
                    else:
                        print('wrong try again')
                        pygame.mixer.Sound.play(wrong)
                        pygame.mixer.music.stop()
                        time.sleep(3)
            time.sleep(4)
      
       
       elif i== 2:

        carImg = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path,'monkey.jpg'))
        gameDisplay.blit(carImg,(130,0))
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.mixer.Sound.play(Monkey)
        pygame.mixer.music.stop()
         
        for a in range(1,4):
                    r = sr.Recognizer()
                    with sr.Microphone() as source:
            
                     print ('Say Something!')
                     audio = r.listen(source)
                    try:
                        text = r.recognize_google(audio)
                        print(text)
                    except:
                        print('Did not get that try Again')
                        text=''
        
                    if text == 'monkey':
                        print('good job') 
                        pygame.mixer.Sound.play(right)
                        pygame.mixer.music.stop()
                        break
                    else:
                        print('wrong ya wad')
                        pygame.mixer.Sound.play(wrong)
                        pygame.mixer.music.stop()
                        time.sleep(3)
        time.sleep(4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a variable named something like 'guess_counter' to keep track of how many time they've answered wrong, and while that number is < 3, (since you said they will have 3 chances) you can play the sound effect for wrong.

Once you move to the next pic, you can reset this counter variable to keep track of guesses for the new pic.

```
for i in range(1,11):
   
   
   if i== 1:
        guess_counter = 0
        carImg = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path,'tiger.jpg'))
        gameDisplay.blit(carImg,(130,0))
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.mixer.Sound.play(Tiger)
        pygame.mixer.music.stop()
        time.sleep(7)
        for j in range(1,4):
                r = sr.Recognizer()
                with sr.Microphone() as source:
        
                print ('Say Something!')
                audio = r.listen(source)
                try:
                    text = r.recognize_google(audio)
                    print(text)
                except:
                    print('Did not get that try Again')
                    text=''
        
                if text == 'tiger':
                    print('good job') 
                    pygame.mixer.Sound.play(right)
                    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
                    break
                else:
                    if guess_counter < 3:
                        print('wrong try again')
                        pygame.mixer.Sound.play(wrong)
                        pygame.mixer.music.stop()
                        time.sleep(3)
                        guess_counter += 1
        time.sleep(4)
  
   
   elif i== 2:
       guess_counter = 0
       carImg = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path,'monkey.jpg'))
       gameDisplay.blit(carImg,(130,0))
       pygame.display.update()
       pygame.mixer.Sound.play(Monkey)
       pygame.mixer.music.stop()
     
       for a in range(1,4):
                r = sr.Recognizer()
                with sr.Microphone() as source:
        
                print ('Say Something!')
                audio = r.listen(source)
                try:
                    text = r.recognize_google(audio)
                    print(text)
                except:
                    print('Did not get that try Again')
                    text=''
    
                if text == 'monkey':
                    print('good job') 
                    pygame.mixer.Sound.play(right)
                    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
                    break
                else:
                    if guess_counter < 3:
                        print('wrong ya wad')
                        pygame.mixer.Sound.play(wrong)
                        pygame.mixer.music.stop()
                        time.sleep(3)
                        guess_counter += 1
    time.sleep(4)
```